# Подгон текста вокруг диаграммы

Tags: html, css

[image: l]

Имеется диаграмма с левой стороны и текст с правой стороны. Подскажите, каким методом я могу подогнать этот текст. Слева у меня див в котором данная диграмма и текст и с правой стороны див, думал сделать  в один див + position absolute, но мне кажется что есть лучшее решения.

Comment: вам придется разбить текст на строки и позиционировать каждую с помощью `margin-left`, `padding-left` или `position:relative; left:%n%px`. Обтекание по кругу не получится без возни с svg - `div`'ы всегда прямоугольные, даже если скруглены.

Comment: вот блин, ну спасибо

Comment: это не совсем на svg html css делается, к примеру на d3.js есть уже готовые реализации но отличающиеся оформлением